# Drupal 7: drupal_add_js() is not adding .js file

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I want to add a .js file to my site and have it appear in the `<head>`

To do this I added the following to the theme's template.php file:

```
   function mytheme_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
      drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('theme', 'mytheme') . '/myfile.js', array(
        'type' => 'file',
        'group' => JS_THEME,
        'scope' => 'header',
      ));
   }
```

But nothing appears when I check the source code (note the .js file is in the theme root directory).

I also tried

```
drupal_add_js('jQuery(document).ready(function () { console.log("Hello!"); });', 'inline');
```

But got nothing.

Would anyone know why this is occuring and what I could do?

Comment: Is your theme actually called "mytheme"?

Comment: @2pha no it's not, I changed it here for privacy

Comment: @MeltingDog mytheme_preprocess_page(&$variables)  hook is fired ? All cache cleared ? cache theme & registry ? memcache ?

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/adding-stylesheets-css-and-javascript-js-to-a-drupal-8-theme